# McDonald's Canada location Scrape, missing phone number

Tags: json, ajax, csv, web-scraping

So below is my scrape for Mcdonalds Canada, I get back most of the information I want.However, I am having issues where I don't get back the phone number.(took it out or rest wont work) In addition, to when my csv file is created it leaves gaps between each cell.From my guess for the phone number not showing, is that it might be under different header or other variation.If anyone has a solution that would be great, the main concern is getting the number and secondary is having no gaps in the csv file.

```
import requests
import csv
import json

url = "https://www.mcdonalds.com/googleapps/GoogleRestaurantLocAction.do?method=searchLocation&latitude=43.6936965&longitude=-79.2969938&radius=1000000&maxResults=1700&country=ca&language=en-ca&showClosed=&hours24Text=Open%2024%20hr"

payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.mcdonalds.com',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
  'accept': '*/*',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'referer': 'https://www.mcdonalds.com/ca/en-ca/restaurant-locator.html',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
  'cookie': 'bm_sz=C04645E7F7A956C5F9D9C5A20DEAEC97~YAAQ1Cv2SEtfMBN6AQAAItxfEwwTVV2V2Tr7UWpPt1Ps7gl84FzQlmbWIm4kBBh5dxlK3w8RenwiEiKtvERE6dLmrwPwJUuy+14gU/LeEZvP+uxzyBr04oQXdcSEQuiOgdkAGasqnBrTw1mp5E5iehnRpvHBDdSqh8wRSgJV0eG4f8YwSz66BfntCBALtQNCAFK2; _abck=F05779F2345218EA4989FF467D897C5A~0~YAAQ1Cv2SExfMBN6AQAAItxfEwaIwCrBeP25JBhBb7TX+HmnLQgrj1TkosrB+oHSv9ctrxRukqEDUaHPL1KkjpqjY1XY1yyulQ0ZRhsEfhY968YVsTOqfiosAu3kykd3pJG/bQ37XHwWs5qXpIdhMXRwJwXmkYtl3ETG8kXK2iZ22Q31COaSjNVACLaa7s9tCk9ItgLvUj5x9Nldjnd8AdXR0pXicrQY1IaruJyNqwMcJv42AUHW7iH4Ex9ZOSYsgEjLMNd44mS525X/gSNUTSOzoqoWsnH4MU59vfgLTwc2hVncAv67LBViTLxbWw4eVAvz7Z5phQfCmvoIy0PD8gy5iwPDMaD3GASrK9xScDPAPUI2wquxmSJ+f2cQaxZQKhvJCeH9cz14OZfx8ksA2ss53E0l0kDvgmnw~-1~-1~-1; ak_bmsc=BA4817D8DEE20E92C1E6251C54FC124348F62BD48F5F00005F91C9608B679D5F~plUkbYfsvYr5dCayJ9dMGEJ3QDgkmkv2mLpE7pCY9vW0xrdawvmyxfSnupw/4F7C48Akdn8PKsBniqz+7F+RZb8v4AkvH3c0RuvnynqJoni+kJcDYtPOxdMvdtGdTlZGIkSQNfpcxHNQDVlzojdSBX0vyBh/8seKQv10U67M7m787olYzg9jnsUwk3/VHBrnMDogiWJT8rNV7saSXunN0pAgucZWo/XhCpTJL+tI9urt0=; MCDCountry_code=US; bm_mi=BEE06312635FD442995BC0237BAFDA7C~f/RxgMW/JJSUc/wB9ZRg9fPD/76+wq/TaoWEZR1/ttrAiVTO256xhDTsVYc/kdHIjWkxvfO4XDcBjqe4hQ4qXt8Anpfi09vna/zcC7l6OVWpWeRSoZNztl7h5VF407L3XG+9CpzjSHNcaqAPRk5d0J5gLMtL/KmR8XBkAC0Syim7ST97nxNrPfLdlkSPMGm4Oy86xvY5PH5Nu47zS/gwhanBFg69tAdrQdaZewE2eGuzoJPsZit3UsihTzhXc4LY92hfSdh3/kZRId+NE8Jp0w==; bm_sv=7CACE3495320A7C0A6CF8F41DFE0EB36~F9KzvznVNk/fE4+ijLD5H/szY7O161rWlemmShElumIW7HN49Gq2d9Sd2tqBjCa9sJOX4zoehAkc8WvsID5Idon/hDlDeLJZuqnEmff4PN4a9yst3R170rBCm1egzGvCBmB1jq9aCwQm5VgIJgloPOdpiIPfD3kDxFbKhqMuS5U=; JSESSIONID=64PZkBXhhpvNjM4NganzSZ0r1npIIaM7Fo84EsxN.eap7node7; _abck=F05779F2345218EA4989FF467D897C5A~-1~YAAQ1Cv2SExyMBN6AQAA5Et0EwZueCejZbKz1VDGCq2sB43Yx4dq0SiiGeUS6gVpXRIdw3rA3OdpNGHq7tVzQ+IvPpEKwLML9736x1qB5SQxV3jai89y2B2QF6K8nKtyrDAes0qbeTyIrHu0Rh1HLs7CjNxiLi0wswbCZfSsPI6fJZiEt+Itre3lfmua/HkhIRwpVTKqlVN5eQ8XIX+s1jJbINx/jUmMTW+jB5k4A5NARGChYH7rJQGYIT/oyZYpSbS3Yweqa4FRgGMW4gYZBN39+t2xSfewADLdpihfOnoZtakw9VhcvAKaf4mEzjB7WEfNJIZSjSE8DzvbJNIF41MGuAhhrnEBwBE8uVCZsA+2qjVPSADVp2Nn8JanJXCbucnLFOLsmPz3oVtGzentht1cHog4+eYOUlmw~0~-1~-1; bm_sv=7CACE3495320A7C0A6CF8F41DFE0EB36~F9KzvznVNk/fE4+ijLD5H/szY7O161rWlemmShElumIW7HN49Gq2d9Sd2tqBjCa9sJOX4zoehAkc8WvsID5Idon/hDlDeLJZuqnEmff4PN5ZCTzA250oKEeVeXaa6j4gEGJ9RRtrTXQdYXzzSx6fM9aLwif+We2vtIc1yLQgTt4=',
  'dnt': '1'
} 

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, data = payload, files = files)


stores = json.loads(response.text)

with open('McdonlocationWORK.csv', mode='w') as CSVFile:
    writer = csv.writer(CSVFile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    writer.writerow([
        "addressLine1",
        "addressLine2",
        "addressLine3",
        "subDivision",
        "postcode",
        ])

    for store in stores['features']:
        row = []
        Match_Address1 = store['properties']["addressLine1"]
        Match_Address2 = store['properties']["addressLine2"]
        Match_Address3 = store['properties']["addressLine3"]
        subDivision = store['properties']["subDivision"]
        Postalcode = store['properties']["postcode"]                      
        

        row.append(Match_Address1)
        row.append(Match_Address2)
        row.append(Match_Address3)
        row.append(subDivision)
        row.append(Postalcode)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict.get` to get telephone number (or in case it doesn't exist provide a default value, in my example "N/A"):

```py
import csv
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.mcdonalds.com/googleapps/GoogleRestaurantLocAction.do?method=searchLocation&latitude=43.6936965&longitude=-79.2969938&radius=1000000&maxResults=1700&country=ca&language=en-ca&showClosed=&hours24Text=Open%2024%20hr"

payload = {}
files = {}
headers = {
    "authority": "www.mcdonalds.com",
    "sec-ch-ua": '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    "accept": "*/*",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "referer": "https://www.mcdonalds.com/ca/en-ca/restaurant-locator.html",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "cookie": "bm_sz=C04645E7F7A956C5F9D9C5A20DEAEC97~YAAQ1Cv2SEtfMBN6AQAAItxfEwwTVV2V2Tr7UWpPt1Ps7gl84FzQlmbWIm4kBBh5dxlK3w8RenwiEiKtvERE6dLmrwPwJUuy+14gU/LeEZvP+uxzyBr04oQXdcSEQuiOgdkAGasqnBrTw1mp5E5iehnRpvHBDdSqh8wRSgJV0eG4f8YwSz66BfntCBALtQNCAFK2; _abck=F05779F2345218EA4989FF467D897C5A~0~YAAQ1Cv2SExfMBN6AQAAItxfEwaIwCrBeP25JBhBb7TX+HmnLQgrj1TkosrB+oHSv9ctrxRukqEDUaHPL1KkjpqjY1XY1yyulQ0ZRhsEfhY968YVsTOqfiosAu3kykd3pJG/bQ37XHwWs5qXpIdhMXRwJwXmkYtl3ETG8kXK2iZ22Q31COaSjNVACLaa7s9tCk9ItgLvUj5x9Nldjnd8AdXR0pXicrQY1IaruJyNqwMcJv42AUHW7iH4Ex9ZOSYsgEjLMNd44mS525X/gSNUTSOzoqoWsnH4MU59vfgLTwc2hVncAv67LBViTLxbWw4eVAvz7Z5phQfCmvoIy0PD8gy5iwPDMaD3GASrK9xScDPAPUI2wquxmSJ+f2cQaxZQKhvJCeH9cz14OZfx8ksA2ss53E0l0kDvgmnw~-1~-1~-1; ak_bmsc=BA4817D8DEE20E92C1E6251C54FC124348F62BD48F5F00005F91C9608B679D5F~plUkbYfsvYr5dCayJ9dMGEJ3QDgkmkv2mLpE7pCY9vW0xrdawvmyxfSnupw/4F7C48Akdn8PKsBniqz+7F+RZb8v4AkvH3c0RuvnynqJoni+kJcDYtPOxdMvdtGdTlZGIkSQNfpcxHNQDVlzojdSBX0vyBh/8seKQv10U67M7m787olYzg9jnsUwk3/VHBrnMDogiWJT8rNV7saSXunN0pAgucZWo/XhCpTJL+tI9urt0=; MCDCountry_code=US; bm_mi=BEE06312635FD442995BC0237BAFDA7C~f/RxgMW/JJSUc/wB9ZRg9fPD/76+wq/TaoWEZR1/ttrAiVTO256xhDTsVYc/kdHIjWkxvfO4XDcBjqe4hQ4qXt8Anpfi09vna/zcC7l6OVWpWeRSoZNztl7h5VF407L3XG+9CpzjSHNcaqAPRk5d0J5gLMtL/KmR8XBkAC0Syim7ST97nxNrPfLdlkSPMGm4Oy86xvY5PH5Nu47zS/gwhanBFg69tAdrQdaZewE2eGuzoJPsZit3UsihTzhXc4LY92hfSdh3/kZRId+NE8Jp0w==; bm_sv=7CACE3495320A7C0A6CF8F41DFE0EB36~F9KzvznVNk/fE4+ijLD5H/szY7O161rWlemmShElumIW7HN49Gq2d9Sd2tqBjCa9sJOX4zoehAkc8WvsID5Idon/hDlDeLJZuqnEmff4PN4a9yst3R170rBCm1egzGvCBmB1jq9aCwQm5VgIJgloPOdpiIPfD3kDxFbKhqMuS5U=; JSESSIONID=64PZkBXhhpvNjM4NganzSZ0r1npIIaM7Fo84EsxN.eap7node7; _abck=F05779F2345218EA4989FF467D897C5A~-1~YAAQ1Cv2SExyMBN6AQAA5Et0EwZueCejZbKz1VDGCq2sB43Yx4dq0SiiGeUS6gVpXRIdw3rA3OdpNGHq7tVzQ+IvPpEKwLML9736x1qB5SQxV3jai89y2B2QF6K8nKtyrDAes0qbeTyIrHu0Rh1HLs7CjNxiLi0wswbCZfSsPI6fJZiEt+Itre3lfmua/HkhIRwpVTKqlVN5eQ8XIX+s1jJbINx/jUmMTW+jB5k4A5NARGChYH7rJQGYIT/oyZYpSbS3Yweqa4FRgGMW4gYZBN39+t2xSfewADLdpihfOnoZtakw9VhcvAKaf4mEzjB7WEfNJIZSjSE8DzvbJNIF41MGuAhhrnEBwBE8uVCZsA+2qjVPSADVp2Nn8JanJXCbucnLFOLsmPz3oVtGzentht1cHog4+eYOUlmw~0~-1~-1; bm_sv=7CACE3495320A7C0A6CF8F41DFE0EB36~F9KzvznVNk/fE4+ijLD5H/szY7O161rWlemmShElumIW7HN49Gq2d9Sd2tqBjCa9sJOX4zoehAkc8WvsID5Idon/hDlDeLJZuqnEmff4PN5ZCTzA250oKEeVeXaa6j4gEGJ9RRtrTXQdYXzzSx6fM9aLwif+We2vtIc1yLQgTt4=",
    "dnt": "1",
}

response = requests.request(
    "GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files
)
stores = json.loads(response.text)

with open("data.csv", mode="w") as CSVFile:
    writer = csv.writer(
        CSVFile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
    )

    writer.writerow(
        [
            "address",
            "subdivision",
            "postcode",
            "telephone",
        ]
    )

    for store in stores["features"]:
        address = " ".join(
            [
                store["properties"]["addressLine1"],
                store["properties"]["addressLine2"],
                store["properties"]["addressLine3"],
                store["properties"]["addressLine4"],
            ]
        )
        sub_division = store["properties"]["subDivision"]
        post_code = store["properties"]["postcode"]
        telephone = store["properties"].get("telephone", "N/A")

        writer.writerow([address, sub_division, post_code, telephone])
```

Creates `data.csv` (screenshot from Libre Office):

[image]

Comment: how would I separate the subdivision from address and possibly the walmart tag? Also I saw you did have sub division separate but blank in the output csv?

Comment: @John_Muir You can remove the column `subdivision` if it is blank on every row. Also, to extract the `(Wal-Mart)` tag you can use `re` module.